# Equalizer, BassBoost и Virtualizer на глобальном уровне

Tags: android

Я кручусь вокруг да около, но чего-то не понимаю. Вот этот код:

```
private BassBoost bass;
private Equalizer EQ;
private Virtualizer virt;

 void try_init(){
 EQ=new Equalizer(999,0);
 bass=new BassBoost(999,0);
 virt=new Virtualizer(999,0);
}
```

не работает. При попытке вызвать функцию try_init(), программа крашится. ID аудиосессии 0 - попытка заставить работать глобально. Если подставить туда любое положительное значение, то работает без ошибок. Что я не так делаю? Как применить эти эффекты глобально?

Answer (score 2):

Все те функции требуют наличия

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

в манифесте. После добавления этой строчки в манифест всё заработало.

UPD: Так же выяснилось, что с какого-то момента использование глобального потока(0) было объявлено устаревшим и теперь не работает.